# Curious about what kind of patent to get?

Tags: patent-services

I'm not sure what kind of a patent to get. Let's say the sticker fad in the culture is to buy a quantity of stickers that are sold on a sheet of peel away paper, and that was the only way of buying them. All of a sudden a guy comes along with the idea to sell single individual stickers in packets rather than on a sheet altogether. Can a patent be placed to rule out the competitors from copying stickers being sold individually this way?

Answer (score 1):

Very doubtful unless there was a technical hurdle to overcome to have them exist individually.